# Broadcast Receiver with custom intent not getting called in API 29

Tags: android

I am writing broadcast receiver with custom Intent in the Manifest file

```
   <receiver
            android:name=".SimpleBroadcast"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="one.two.three" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

My SimpleBroadcast is following simple file

```
public class SimpleBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        //hrow new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        Toast.makeText(context,"my broadcast called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("life","got");
    }
}
```

However when i call this from my Activity nothing happens.
However the same broadcast receiver i can register from my activity and run.
Are custom intents not allowed in api29.
please update.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit broadcasts have been blocked on Android since [Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts), nearly three years ago.